# HL7 V3 Organization identifier to URN:OID

Tags: urn, hl7-v3

I need to transform an HL7 V3 Organization identifier (root+extension) to an URN.

Organization id is as follows:

```
<Organization xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <id>
        <item root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.2" extensions="26879954"/>
    </id>
```

...
As fas as I know I can use "URN:OID:2.16.840.1.113883.4.2"

But how to add extension value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot. Organization `<id>` is the Instance Identifier (`II`) data type. The II data type identifies the root as “*a unique identifier that guarantees the global uniqueness of the instance identifier. The root alone may be the entire instance identifier*” and the extension as “*a character string as a unique identifier within the scope of the identifier root*”. In it turns, the root “*must be a valid OID, UUID, or HL7 reserved identifier*” so you cannot put an URN.

As an option, you may register your own OIDs as following - *2.16.840.1.113883.4.2*.**26879954** – in this case you need to keep a reference table to uniquely identify organizations.

The difference between these two is that in the fist case you identify a scoping authority and the organization within that authority. In the second case you identify an organization as a separate unique entity which does not belong to any scoping sets.

See HL7v3 Normative Edition for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reviewing [HL7 CCDA documentation](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=258)! , and I see some HL7 CCDA templates expressed as: urn:hl7ii:2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.10:2014-06-09

So I guess the right way to represent an HL7 V3 id as URN:OID is:
urn:hl7ii:{root}:{extension}